# I can use &(*struct)->name but not struct->name, when they both mean the same?

Tags: c, struct

> Thanks for all the help, I was just getting the order of operations wrong and I was forgetting that I don't need & before a pointer, as that is done automatically. My goal was to find a shorter way than using &(*head) and I thought that only head might do it somehow as I got confused using the debugger.

Just a quick question guys, nothing major.

This is my problematic function in its working state:

```
void getInput_stock(stock **head, char fgr, char bgr)
{
    scanStr(&(*head)->name, 60);
}
```

This is what scanStr looks like:

```
int scanStr(char *input, int limit);
```

I've been dealing with structs since quite some time but they still confuse me. I made a breakpoint at `scanStr(&(*head)->name, 60);` and I checked variables `&(*head)` and `head`, they were both returning the same address. But when I try to use `scanStr(head->name, 60);` instead of the example given at the top of the post, I get an error `left of '->name' must point to struct/union`. I believe it IS a pointer to a struct. Why am I getting this error? I mean isn't `&(*var)` the same as `var`?

```
struct stockNode {
    int ID;
    int price[2];
    int qty;
    int date[3];
    unsigned int number[2];
    char name[60];
    char nameProv[60];
    char town[14];
    char street[30];
    struct stockNode *next;
};
typedef struct stockNode stock;
```

Comment: `->` binds stronger than `&` (all postfix operators bind stronger than all prefix operators). `&(*head)->name` is the same as `&((*head)->name)`.

Comment: the `->` operator has higher precedence than `*` and `&`. BTW: in this case you dont need the `&`, since name is an array.

Comment: Show definition of struct stock?

Comment: Oh I get it, so using head->name is like (&(*head))->name and it should be &((*head)->name)?

Comment: Besides what others have said, you shouldn't use `&` here at all. `(*head)->name` is correct.

Comment: interjay, you're right. Correct me if I am wrong, I need to use & when modifying any integer values.

Comment: You need `&` if (for example) you have `int` and need `int*`. Here you have `char[60]` and need `char*`, and the conversion from array to pointer is done automatically.

Comment: Not only that, but the version with `&` has type "pointer to array of char", which is not compatible with "pointer to char", and should cause your compiler to complain about incompatible types. To be explicit, you could say `&(*head)->name[0]`, but most folks seem to think that it's preferable to avoid `&array[0]` and just write `array` and rely on the automatic conversion.

Comment: @EduardGeorgiev I think fundamentally you are having difficulties with the pointer syntax more than anything related to the struct. `getInput_stock(stock **head, ...` passes `head` as a **pointer-to-pointer-to-struct**. You need to reference `head` in your function as a **pointer-to-struct**. How? The same way you handle any pointer, **dereference it**. As stated `(*head)->name` is correct. If it helps, just add an intermediate assignment `stock *node = *head;` in your function and then use `scanStr(node->name, 60);` Just revisit pointer handling and your problem will be solved.

Comment: This got downvoted. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

As `name` is a member of the `stock` struct - accessing one of its members is simply using the `->` operator when the variable is a pointer to the struct.

In your usage

```
void getInput_stock(stock **head, char fgr, char bgr)
{
    scanStr(&(*head)->name, 60);
}
```

the `head` is a pointer to a `stock` pointer - this means first reference to it `(*head)` becomes a pointer to `stock`, therefore accessing its member needs simple `->` operator usage.

Your function should be

```
void getInput_stock(stock **head, char fgr, char bgr)
{
    scanStr((*head)->name, 60);
}
```